# How to draw a menu separator?

Tags: android

I would like to draw a separator between two views.  I am aware that I can draw a line between the views with the xml below, but it's pretty ugly.  I'd like it to be more like the menu separator used in java; beveled and rounded and such.  Any advice on how to achieve this effect?

```
<View
    android:layout_width="3dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">
 </View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a wide variety of drawables. 
Here's a couple ideas :

1. Your view could have a rounded rectangle or an ellipse filled with a gradient as a background (the android documentation has them all)
2. You could use a 9 patch image of a nice looking separator

Comment: thanks.  your gradient recommendation led me to this post: http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=34.  which looks great, with some tweaking.